# Difference between pushing and merging

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

Say that I have a master branch and development branch which I am working on. I want to merge development with master branch.

Are there any differences between pusing development branch to master or switch to master branch then merging development branch into master branch ?

Answer (score 4):

*Merging* is a local operation, while *pushing* operates on a remote repository.  These two things are unrelated in a Git context.

In order to merge two branches, you check out either one and then run `git merge <other>`.  In your case, you probably want to merge `development` into `master`, so you will do

```
git checkout master
git merge development
```

After that, you might want to perform a `git push` operation in order to update the remote repository, but that is unrelated to the merge operation.

Answer (score -1):

This **Article** might help here:
http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/

It the comparison between **git pull vs git fetch then merge**, which is similar to this scenario.

Comment: Does not address his question.